# Stacking Nginx on top of Jhipster Gateway

Tags: nginx, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

We are creating an application following an microservice architecture using Jhipster, and now someone suggested putting an Nginx in front of the Jhipster gateway so user access goes through Nginx instead of directly through the Jhipster gateway, and my question is there any benefit in doing this? Since from my perspective we are just proxying twice the requests nothing else, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be useful for:

- load balancing multiple instances of your gateway
- restrict external access to some URLs if you have an internal access to your gateway
- blue/green deployments